# Unwanted output from JavaScript Coderbyte

Tags: javascript

Hi guys I am working on the following CoderByte problem.

> Using the JavaScript language, have the function PermutationStep(num)
>   take the num parameter being passed and return the next number greater
>   than num using the same digits. For example: if num is 123 return 132,
>   if it's 12453 return 12534. If a number has no greater permutations,
>   return -1 (ie. 999).
>
> Use the Parameter Testing feature in the box below to test your code
>   with different arguments.

My code is

```
var PermutationStep = function(num){
var newNum = num.toString().split("");
for(var i = (newNum.length - 1); i >= 0; i--){
    if(newNum[i] > newNum[i-1]){
        newNum.splice(i-1,2,newNum[i],newNum[i-1]);
        var firstHalf = newNum.slice(0,i);
        var secondHalf = newNum.slice(i);
        break;
    }
    else{
        return -1;
    }

}

var sorted = secondHalf.sort(function(a,b){return a - b});
return firstHalf.concat(sorted).join("");

};
```

My code consists of looping through an array of the number and switching the terms newNum[i-1] and newNum[i] when newNum[i] > newNum[i - 1] and then taking all numbers to the right of these two terms and sorting them. Logically this works, but my code is not behaving the way I would like it to. For example `PermutationStep(112211)` returns -1 when it should be returning `121112`. Can anyone help me debug this?

Comment: why should PermutationStep(112211) return 121122 instead of 112212?

Comment: It's the next greatest number using the digits in the input.

Comment: but isn't 121122 bigger than 112212, and aren't both bigger than 112211? (just trying to see if i can figure out exactly what you need so i can find a solution)

Comment: Sorry my mistake it should be return 121112 the next largest number using only the digits in the input. Does that make sense?

Answer (score 1):

Make sure you are dealing with numbers and not strings when doing comparisons/evaluating numbers... A big problem I have run into with JS is numbers being evaluated as a string. Try wrapping your `newNum[i]` variable in the `Number()` function like this `Number(newNum[i])`.

Try the below code.

```
var PermutationStep = function (num) {
    var newNum = num.toString().split("");
    for (var i = (newNum.length - 1); i >= 0; i--) {
        if (Number(newNum[i]) > Number(newNum[i - 1])) {
            newNum.splice(i - 1, 2, newNum[i], newNum[i - 1]);
            var firstHalf = newNum.slice(0, i);
            var secondHalf = newNum.slice(i);
            break;
        }
        else {
            return -1;
        }

    }

    var sorted = secondHalf.sort(function (a, b) { return Number(a) - Number(b) });
    return firstHalf.concat(sorted).join("");

};
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
function permutationStep(num) {
    const permutations = Array.from(
        new Set( // use Set to filter for unique values
            permute(num.toString().split(''))
                .map(number => number.join(''))
                .map(Number)
        )
    );

    permutations.sort((a, b) => a - b);

    const largerPermutations = permutations.filter(
        permutation => permutation > num
    );

    if (largerPermutations.length > 0) {
        return largerPermutations[0];
    }
    return -1;
}

// https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Heap's_algorithm
// Iterative
function permute(arr) {
    let count = Array(arr.length).fill(0);

    const results = [arr.slice()];

    let i = 0;
    while (i < arr.length) {
        if (count[i] < i) {
            if (i % 2 === 0) {
                const temp = arr[0];
                arr[0] = arr[i];
                arr[i] = temp;
            } else {
                const temp = arr[count[i]];
                arr[count[i]] = arr[i];
                arr[i] = temp;
            }
            results.push(arr.slice());
            count[i]++;
            i = 0;
        } else {
            count[i] = 0;
            i++;
        }
    }
    return results;
}

console.log(permutationStep(41352))
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved by adding explanation for how the code works to help future visitors :)